# I wanted to Automate AS400 application using Python script, like login to application and selecting some options

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, ibm-midrange

I heard we can use antiomony module in python, but that is not installing or may be is not supported in python version >=3.7

Can anyone help me on this, how can we automate login in AS400 application

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated the Python XMLSERVICE Toolkit for IBM i yet? It's available here:

https://github.com/IBM/python-itoolkit

https://github.com/IBM/xmlservice

Another approach is to access REST APIs on IBM i from your Python programs. The IBM i operating system includes the Integrated Web Services for IBM i at no additional charge, and this component provides bidirectional REST APIs (JSON/HTTPS) directly on IBM i.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/integrated-web-services-ibm-i-web-services-made-easy

Note that you can run Python programs directly on IBM i. This article explains the basic details:

https://www.itjungle.com/2019/06/10/guru-getting-started-with-python-on-ibm-i/

By the way, you almost certainly don't have an IBM AS/400 server. IBM hasn't manufactured any AS/400 machines for nearly 20 years. You're probably referring to the successor platform, now called IBM i, which runs on IBM Power Systems. So if you're struggling to find answers then that could by why.